# JConsole for remote JMX access against JBoss AS7 standalone mode

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

I am trying to access Jconsole for monitoring JBoss of a remote machine in the same intranet, but I am getting:
**Connection failed! The connection to user@service:jmx:remoting-jmx://192.168.124.x:9999 did not succeed.**

OS: Ubuntu, 
Command: *./jconsole -J-Djava.class.path=/home/stpl/software/jdk1.7.0_51/lib/jconsole.jar:/home/stpl/software/jdk1.7.0_51/lib/jconsole.jar/tools.jar:/home/stpl/software/jboss-as-7.1.1:/home/stpl/software/jdk1.7.0_51/lib/tools.jar*

In the machine which I want to access I have done following changes:
**standalone.xml**: All inet address from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 and 
remoting-connector use-management-endpoint="false".

In standalone.conf added following:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS -Djava.awt.headless=true"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.platform.mbeanserver"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.124.31"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -Xbootclasspath/p:../modules/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-1.2.2.GA.jar  -Xbootclasspath/p:../modules/org/jboss/logmanager/log4j/main/jboss-logmanager-log4j-1.0.0.GA.jar -Xbootclasspath/p:../modules/org/apache/log4j/main/log4j-1.2.16.jar"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.logmanager"
```

I can access admin console from the remote machine and can telnet successfully for port 9999.

Kindly tell the clear steps for the same as I googled a lot but couldn't succeed to find solution .
Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried the `$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jconsole.sh`?

Comment: It worked for me from $JBOSS_HOME/bin/jconsole.sh, and emoting-connector use-management-endpoint="true"

Answer (score 0):

This worked for after following changes:

In standalone.xml, added **remoting-connector use-management-endpoint="true"**

like:-

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.1"> 
     <show-model value="true"/> 
     <remoting-connector use-management-endpoint="true"/> 
</subsystem>
```

Instead of running from JDK run this command from JBoss bin:
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jconsole.sh

No configuration changes required in standalone.conf

In jconsole.sh set path for the JAVA_HOME and JBOSS_HOME and following jar classpath:

CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/jconsole.jar
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar 
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/home/stpl/software/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/client/jboss-client.jar